# How to find text in between specific div using class {web-scraping beautifulsoupe python}

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the part from which i need to scrape the text in div class = '_2qgs'
and as i am scraping it shows blank in output

Link from which i m scraping text = [Link](https://www.facebook.com/events/1407771472571452/)

Scraped text stored in **data** variable from which i need to find text in div class = ''

```
[<div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_8"><!-- <div class="_4-u2 _5z71 _18ib _4-u8"><div class="_4-u3 _5z73"><div class="clearfix"><div class="lfloat _ohe"><a class="_5z74" href="/events/dialog/public_guest_list/?acontext%5Bref%5D=51&amp;acontext%5Bsource%5D=1&amp;acontext%5Baction_history%5D=%5B%7B%22surface%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22mechanism%22%3A%22surface%22%2C%22extra_data%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%22surface%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22mechanism%22%3A%22guest_list%22%2C%22extra_data%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D&amp;acontext%5Bhas_source%5D=1&amp;event_id=1407771472571452" rel="dialog" role="button">560 \u091c\u093e \u0930\u0939\u0947 \u0939\u0948\u0902&nbsp;\xb7&nbsp;3.1 \u0939\u091c\u093c\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u0940 \u0930\u0941\u091a\u093f \u0939\u0948</a><div class="_5z7d">\u0907\u0938 \u0908\u0935\u0947\u0902\u091f \u0915\u094b \u0905\u092a\u0928\u0947 \u092e\u093f\u0924\u094d\u0930\u094b\u0902 \u0938\u0947 \u0938\u093e\u091d\u093e \u0915\u0930\u0947\u0902</div></div><a class="_42ft _4jy0 _i8v _3-8w rfloat _ohf _4jy4 _517h _51sy" role="button" href="#" ajaxify="#" rel="dialog" data-testid="event_invite_button"><i class="_3-8_ _3-8_ img sp_WYmAGAVQNZh sx_82e44d"></i>\u0906\u092e\u0902\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093f\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0947\u0902</a></div></div></div> --></code></div>, <div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_i"><!-- <div class="_5vl5 _3a9j"><ul class="uiList _4kg _4ks"><li class="_3slj"><div class="_36hm"><table class="uiGrid _51mz" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- _phw"><div class="_6a" aria-hidden="true"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:18px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><i class="_ohg img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_c2b8bd"><u>clock</u></i></div></div></td><td class="_51m- _4930 _phw _51mw"><div class="_xkh _phw"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:18px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="_publicProdFeedInfo__timeRowTitle _5xhk" content="2017-07-28T21:30:00-07:00 to 2017-07-29T05:00:00-07:00"><span><span itemprop="startDate">29 \u091c\u0941\u0932\u093e\u0908</span></span> <span title="09:30 &#x905;&#x92a;&#x930;&#x93e;&#x939;&#x94d;&#x928; &#x906;&#x92a;&#x915;&#x947; &#x938;&#x92e;&#x92f; &#x92e;&#x947;&#x902;">10:00 \u092a\u0942\u0930\u094d\u0935\u093e\u0939\u094d\u0928</span> - <span title="05:00 &#x92a;&#x942;&#x930;&#x94d;&#x935;&#x93e;&#x939;&#x94d;&#x928; &#x906;&#x92a;&#x915;&#x947; &#x938;&#x92e;&#x92f; &#x92e;&#x947;&#x902;">05:30 \u0905\u092a\u0930\u093e\u0939\u094d\u0928 UTC+05:30</span></div><div class="_5xhp fsm fwn fcg"></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></li><li class="_3xd0 _3slj"><div class="_36hm _5cmn" id="u_0_9"><table class="uiGrid _51mz" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- _phw"><div class="_6a" aria-hidden="true"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:32px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><i class="_ohg img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_f4bee6"><u>pin</u></i></div></div></td><td class="_51m- _51mw"><div class="clearfix _4930"><div class="_xkg _phw rfloat _ohf"><div><div id="u_0_a"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:32px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><a href="#" role="button">\u092e\u0948\u092a \u0926\u093f\u0916\u093e\u090f\u0901</a></div></div></div><div class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_b"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:32px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><a href="#" role="button">\u092e\u0948\u092a \u091b\u093f\u092a\u093e\u090f\u0901</a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_xkh _phw _42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:32px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><a class="_5xhk" href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" id="u_0_d" data-testid="event-permalink-location">IIT Delhi</a><div class="_5xhp fsm fwn fcg">Hauz Khaz, New Delhi, India 110016</div></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="_4-u2 hidden_elem _5xhn _4-u8" id="u_0_c"><div class="clearfix _ikh"><div class="_4bl7"><div class="_23mo"><div class="fbPlaceFlyoutWrap _5xho" id="u_0_e"><div class="fbPlaceFlyout" style="width:240px;"><div class="fbPlaceFlyoutShell" style="width:46px;bottom:-31px;"><div class="fbPlaceFlyoutBox uiBoxWhite" style="width: 46px"><div><div class="_52i5"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/"><img class="_s0 img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p40x40/255575_512250575469178_612128240_n.jpg?oh=dc9acf8d4452db344aaba7fde25efa84&amp;oe=59AD9DC7" alt="" itemprop="image" aria-label="IIT Delhi" role="img" style="width:40px;height:40px" /></a></div></div><div class="fbPlaceFlyoutMapArrow"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_104d97"></i></div><div class="fbPlaceFlyoutMapArrow"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_104d97"></i></div></div></div></div><a href="#" rel="dialog" ajaxify="/places/map/?id=211928345501404" role="button"><div><div class="_4j7v _2vs2"><img class="_a3f img" alt="" aria-label="&#x928;&#x915;&#x94d;&#x936;&#x93e; &#x905;&#x91f;&#x948;&#x91a;&#x92e;&#x947;&#x902;&#x91f;" src="https://external.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/static_map.php?region=IN&amp;v=29&amp;osm_provider=2&amp;size=240x132&amp;center=28.545188216208%2C77.193069476906&amp;zoom=15&amp;markers=28.54518822%2C77.19306948&amp;language=hi_IN" width="240" height="132" /><span id="u_0_g"></span></div></div></a></div></div></div><div class="_4bl9 _2qsg"><div><span class="_c24">\u0915\u0949\u0932\u0947\u091c \u0914\u0930 \u092f\u0942\u0928\u093f\u0935\u0930\u094d\u0938\u093f\u091f\u0940</span><div><div class="_4iae"><div><div class="_6a _5xoz _5xo-"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_ac5297"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_ac5297"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_ac5297"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_ac5297"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz _4ial"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_ac5297"></i></div></div><div class="_559j" style="clip: rect(0px, 63px, 16px, 0px)"><div class="_6a _5xoz _5xo-"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_59de11"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_59de11"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_59de11"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_59de11"></i></div><div class="_6a _5xoz _4ial"><i class="img sp_ESbkBsVlxUv sx_59de11"></i></div></div></div></div><hr class="_23mm" /><div><span class="_c24">011 2659 6316</span></div><div><span class="_c24"></span></div><div class="ptm"><a class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" role="button" href="http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fshare.here.com%2Fr%2Fmylocation%2Fe-eyJuYW1lIjoiSUlUIERlbGhpIiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IkhhdXogS2hheiwgTmV3IERlbGhpLCBJbmRpYSAxMTAwMTYiLCJsYXRpdHVkZSI6MjguNTQ1MTg4MjE2MjA4LCJsb25naXR1ZGUiOjc3LjE5MzA2OTQ3NjkwNiwicHJvdmlkZXJOYW1lIjoiZmFjZWJvb2siLCJwcm92aWRlcklkIjoyMTE5MjgzNDU1MDE0MDR9%3Flink%3Dunknown%26fb_locale%3Dhi_IN%26ref%3Dfacebook&amp;h=ATP2RoDOmV19cipyFvxN_S_G4uI7FP1aDGQXs8I8palbouMF9Ut2wIJBE-D0XSb9O2x9_YcBTP1eLGOs-qvz3hHjCMi-5oGqGiE1TJerNdX-KKhRgc6j392SdLAY&amp;s=1" id="u_0_f" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\\/\\\\/share.here.com\\\\/r\\\\/mylocation\\\\/e-eyJuYW1lIjoiSUlUIERlbGhpIiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IkhhdXogS2hheiwgTmV3IERlbGhpLCBJbmRpYSAxMTAwMTYiLCJsYXRpdHVkZSI6MjguNTQ1MTg4MjE2MjA4LCJsb25naXR1ZGUiOjc3LjE5MzA2OTQ3NjkwNiwicHJvdmlkZXJOYW1lIjoiZmFjZWJvb2siLCJwcm92aWRlcklkIjoyMTE5MjgzNDU1MDE0MDR9?link=unknown&amp;fb_locale=hi_IN&amp;ref=facebook&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\\/\\\\/l.facebook.com\\\\/l.php?u=http\\\\u00253A\\\\u00252F\\\\u00252Fshare.here.com\\\\u00252Fr\\\\u00252Fmylocation\\\\u00252Fe-eyJuYW1lIjoiSUlUIERlbGhpIiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IkhhdXogS2hheiwgTmV3IERlbGhpLCBJbmRpYSAxMTAwMTYiLCJsYXRpdHVkZSI6MjguNTQ1MTg4MjE2MjA4LCJsb25naXR1ZGUiOjc3LjE5MzA2OTQ3NjkwNiwicHJvdmlkZXJOYW1lIjoiZmFjZWJvb2siLCJwcm92aWRlcklkIjoyMTE5MjgzNDU1MDE0MDR9\\\\u00253Flink\\\\u00253Dunknown\\\\u002526fb_locale\\\\u00253Dhi_IN\\\\u002526ref\\\\u00253Dfacebook&amp;h=ATP2RoDOmV19cipyFvxN_S_G4uI7FP1aDGQXs8I8palbouMF9Ut2wIJBE-D0XSb9O2x9_YcBTP1eLGOs-qvz3hHjCMi-5oGqGiE1TJerNdX-KKhRgc6j392SdLAY&amp;s=1&quot;);">\u0926\u093f\u0936\u093e\u090f\u0901 \u092a\u094d\u0930\u093e\u092a\u094d\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0947\u0902</a></div></div></div></div></div></li></ul><div id="event_navigation" class="_4dn9"><div id="u_0_h"></div></div></div> --></code></div>, <div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_m"><!-- <div class="_4z-v"><div class="_4-u2 _3xaf _3-95 _4-u8"><div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _57_-"><span class="_38my _5803">\u0935\u093f\u0935\u0930\u0923<span class="_c1c"></span></span><div class="_3s3-"></div></div><div class="_2qgs"><span class="_4n-j _fbReactionComponent__eventDetailsContentTags fsl" data-testid="event-permalink-details">Indian Youth Forum is proud to announce the first-ever Startup Festival 2017 which will bring together the brightest startups of the country all in one place. And these startups are looking to hire you!<br /> For the first time ever, these bright and young startups, will open their ships to technical and non-technical talent, on an adventurous voyage filled with learning to become the next big company. The event is open to working professionals and talented freshers looking for a challenging and enriching role.<br /> <br /> For Any Kind of Association Queries Mail us at -<br /> mystory&#064;indiayf.in or Inbox us .</span></div><div class="_1r51"><ul class="uiList uiCollapsedList uiCollapsedListHidden _509- _4ki" id="u_0_j"><li><a href="/events/discovery/?acontext=%7B%22ref%22%3A51%2C%22source%22%3A1%2C%22action_history%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22surface%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22event_information%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22tag%5C%22%3A%5C%22StartUp%5C%22%7D%7D%5D%22%2C%22has_source%22%3Atrue%7D&amp;suggestion_token=%7B%22tags%22%3A%5B181836542181749%5D%7D"><span class="_47od">StartUp</span></a></li><li><a href="/events/discovery/?acontext=%7B%22ref%22%3A51%2C%22source%22%3A1%2C%22action_history%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22surface%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22event_information%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22tag%5C%22%3A%5C%22Job+hunting%5C%22%7D%7D%5D%22%2C%22has_source%22%3Atrue%7D&amp;suggestion_token=%7B%22tags%22%3A%5B111193155571103%5D%7D"><span class="_47od">Job hunting</span></a></li><li><a href="/events/discovery/?acontext=%7B%22ref%22%3A51%2C%22source%22%3A1%2C%22action_history%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22surface%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%5C%22surface%5C%22%3A%5C%22permalink%5C%22%2C%5C%22mechanism%5C%22%3A%5C%22event_information%5C%22%2C%5C%22extra_data%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22tag%5C%22%3A%5C%22Startup.com%5C%22%7D%7D%5D%22%2C%22has_source%22%3Atrue%7D&amp;suggestion_token=%7B%22tags%22%3A%5B109416335743992%5D%7D"><span class="_47od">Startup.com</span></a></li></ul></div></div><div class="_4-u2 _3xaf _3-95 _4-u8"><div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _57_-"><span class="_38my _5803">Indian Youth Forum \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u093e\u0930\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0902<span class="_c1c"></span></span><div class="_3s3-"></div></div><div><div><div class="_37p5"><div class="clearfix"><img class="_37p7 _8o _8r lfloat _ohe img" height="100" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c5.0.100.100/p100x100/16708216_1083815345075324_1809238266151282211_n.jpg?oh=cdc9096728fec80a0147133a6b1599d6&amp;oe=59E5EFDB" alt="" /><div class="_8u _42ef"><div class="_37p8"><div class="_50f4"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" href="https://www.facebook.com/IyfIndianyouthforum/">Indian Youth Forum</a></span></div><div class="_37p9 _50f3">News &amp; Media Website</div><div class="_37pa _50f3">We find and tell stories of people doing good to inspire global action. Because we&#039;re convinced each of us has the power to make the world better .</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_4-u2 _3xaf _3-95 _4-u8"><div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _57_-"><span class="_38my _5803">\u0938\u094d\u0925\u093e\u0928 \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u093e\u0930\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0902<span class="_c1c"></span></span><div class="_3s3-"></div></div><div class="_37p6"><div><div><div><div class="_4sdm _6lh _dcs"><div class="_5hv6"><div class="_6lp"><div class="_6ln fsxxl fwb"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;k&quot;&#125;">IIT Delhi</a></div><div class="_6lo ellipsis fsm fwn fcg">\u0915\u0949\u0932\u0947\u091c \u0914\u0930 \u092f\u0942\u0928\u093f\u0935\u0930\u094d\u0938\u093f\u091f\u0940</div></div></div><div class="uiScaledImageContainer _6li _6l-" style="width:100%"><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p320x320/1660351_782270428467190_610794429_n.jpg?oh=4b4957698cf37eaa2621307fc3c61b8f&amp;oe=59E14DBB" style="top:-60px;" alt="&#039;Picture credit: Arshad Nasser (2013JDS6003) M.Des- Industrial Design&#039;" width="480" height="320" /></div><a class="_8xh" href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" style="width:100%" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;k&quot;&#125;"></a><a class="_3aml" href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" style="width:100%"></a><div class="clearfix _5kun"><a class="_6ll lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;k&quot;&#125;"><div class="_6lm _4m78"><div class="uiScaledImageContainer profilePic" style="width: 96px; height: 96px"><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/255575_512250575469178_612128240_n.jpg?oh=e2bf449617f68eac2b8cd02d7c35a513&amp;oe=59A0C926" alt="IIT Delhi" width="96" height="96" /></div></div></a><div class="_6lk _42ef"><div><div class="_8yb"><div>2,82,390 \u092a\u0938\u0902\u0926</div><div>2,019 \u0932\u094b\u0917 \u0907\u0938 \u092c\u093e\u0930\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092c\u093e\u0924 \u0915\u0930 \u0930\u0939\u0947 \u0939\u0948\u0902</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_4z-w"><a class="_4b4x" href="https://www.facebook.com/iitd.delhi/" id="u_0_k">\u092a\u0947\u091c \u092a\u0930 \u091c\u093e\u090f\u0901</a></div></div><div class="_4-u2 _3xaf _3-95 _4-u8"><div class="_4x0f"><div class="_4x0g"><div class="_4x0d _4x0e"><div class="_41dr _4x0c"><span><img class="_s0 _41ds _54ru img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c4.15.32.32/p40x40/15747342_1195628017184471_1949447432837553984_n.jpg?oh=54f25e123a74d63f279279ee62318a79&amp;oe=59B5B106" alt="" aria-label="Jha Ayush" role="img" /></span></div><div class="_41dr _4x0c"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/IyfIndianyouthforum/"><img class="_s0 _41ds _54ru img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/15541314_1041942845929241_1722198877754933119_n.jpg?oh=973e318ede53168d58f6e7be835583c0&amp;oe=59A926CC" alt="" aria-label="Indian Youth Forum" role="img" /></a></div><div class="_41dr _4x0c"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kumeshyadav"><img class="_s0 _41ds _54ru img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/15337627_10153988267585286_2118657580809154297_n.jpg?oh=182fa980f18ed2d94c6717f8de3af7ad&amp;oe=599BC3CD" alt="" aria-label="Kumesh Yadav" role="img" /></a></div><div class="_41dr _4x0c"><span><img class="_s0 _41ds _54ru img" src="https://scontent.fdel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/15965812_10158191872490352_4833263074795798396_n.jpg?oh=ce18a15878fc5814539a57aed4c0446b&amp;oe=59A47E1F" alt="" aria-label="Kanika Gupta" role="img" /></span></div></div></div><div class="_4x0h">\u091a\u0930\u094d\u091a\u093e \u092e\u0947\u0902 12 \u092a\u094b\u0938\u094d\u091f.</div></div><div class="_4z-w"><a class="_4b4x" href="/events/1407771472571452/?active_tab=discussion" id="u_0_l">\u091a\u0930\u094d\u091a\u093e \u0926\u0947\u0916\u0947\u0902</a></div></div></div> --></code></div>]
```

Here is the python code that i m using

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
facebook="https://www.facebook.com/events/1407771472571452/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(facebook)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "hidden_elem"})
data    """upto this i m able to scrape but after this i m unable               to find text in data div class = '_2qgs'""" 
for div in soup.findAll('div', class_="_2qgs"):
    print div.text
```

Here i m getting blank output and i using python2.7

Comment: Notice in your 'scraped text' that an HTML comment field opens about 50 characters from the beginning of the string and that this field doesn't close until about ten characters from the end. This implies that most of the string will be ignored by BeautifulSoup. If you want it parsed then you could simply do a string `.replace` for the substrings that mark out the comment.

Comment: @BillBell can you please tell me how to use .replace in code

Comment: @BillBell thanks so much it really helped me a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer on SO does what you need you can mark it 'accepted', if you like.

Comment: while scraping the data form ' div class = "_publicProdFeedInfo__timeRowTitle _5xhk" ' i am getting an encoded text and while text is present in the source code of the url :view-source:https://www.facebook.com/events/1407771472571452/ can  you please tell me how can i resove it

Comment: This looks like it might be a new question. In any case, it would be better to post is as such so that there's space to provide a good answer.

Comment: Almost forgot, I'm willing to try to answer. Just leave a comment for me here when you're posted.

Comment: @BillBell I have posted the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506990/geting-encoded-text-while-scraping-the-data-from-url-using-beautifulsoup-python

Comment: @BillBell sir have you check out the posted question ?

Comment: Just noticed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you asked because it's more complicated than just using `.replace`. (I misunderstood what you were displaying.)

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> facebook="https://www.facebook.com/events/1407771472571452/"
>>> page = requests.get(facebook).content
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> data = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'hidden_elem'})
>>> len(data)
3
>>> for item in data:
...     commentedHTML = item.find('code').contents[0]
...     more_soup = BeautifulSoup(commentedHTML, 'lxml')
...     wanted_text = more_soup.findAll('div', {'class': '_2qgs'})
...     if wanted_text:
...         wanted_text
...         
[<div class="_2qgs"><span class="_4n-j _fbReactionComponent__eventDetailsContentTags fsl" data-testid="event-permalink-details">Indian Youth Forum is proud to announce the first-ever Startup Festival 2017 which will bring together the brightest startups of the country all in one place. And these startups are looking to hire you!<br/> For the first time ever, these bright and young startups, will open their ships to technical and non-technical talent, on an adventurous voyage filled with learning to become the next big company. The event is open to working professionals and talented freshers looking for a challenging and enriching role.<br/> <br/> For Any Kind of Association Queries Mail us at -<br/> mystory@indiayf.in or Inbox us .</span></div>]
```

Now the text you want is available as `wanted_text[0].text`.